# Changes on angular include not taking effect on chrome

Tags: html, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, xampp

I'm using angular ng-include on my page. Every time I make a change on the .html included, the changes doesn't take effect on chrome and Opera, but does take effect on Firefox. I'm using XAMPP to run my page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because of angular's [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache).

A quick solution is to flush your browser's cache, or in Chrome dev tools on the bottom right click on the gear and tick the option `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)`